# Keep R from automatically grabbing latest version of already installed package?

Tags: r, centos, r-package, singularity-container

I'm trying to install R package A into a Singularity container with R 3.6.0. Package A needs R package B as a dependency. I originally installed package A with version 1 of package B, and things worked fine. Now, however, I need to rebuild this setup, and it appears that version 2 of package B has come out. For some reason, package B version 2 doesn't build on my machine, and gives random compiler errors that I can't find any reference to online. I can still install version 1 of package B no problem. However, when I try to install package A, it pulls version 2 of package B from CRAN, even though the correct version (version 1) of package B is already installed, thus making the whole thing not work as version 2 of package B fails to build.

How can I tell R to not grab the latest version of package B, and to just use the one already installed? This is on CentOS 7 building inside of a Singularity container. I'm using the standard "install.packages" function to install package A, and the "install_version" command from devtools to install the specific version of package B. I want to stress that package A is still being installed as the same version, and that the entire issue here stems from R pulling the version 2 of package B, even though the same version of package A originally worked fine with version 1 of package B.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Install the older version of package B using `install_version`
2. Install the new package **without dependencies** using `install.packages("A", dependencies=FALSE)`

Comment: I don't want to downgrade package A, and doing this to install version 1 of package B before trying to install package A simply results in R overruling the existing version 1 of package B and installing version 2, thus causing the build to fail.

Comment: Won't help with `update.packages()`.  The CRAN world view simply is to have all packages _current_ and at their newest version.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use packages in versions that worked for you before. For that find out the date when it worked at put into repo url.

```r
install.packages(
  "A",
  repos="https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-05-15/"
)
```

Before running that command ensure that B is removed.